# 'Endless scroll' in a div on a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, facebook

I want to create a div containing endless scrollable content in a page.

For recognizing the end of the scrollable content in order to load more data from the data base I've written the following:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

  var wintop = $(window).scrollTop(), docheight = $(document).height(), winheight = $(window).height();
  var  scrolltrigger = 0.95;

  if  ((wintop/(docheight-winheight)) > scrolltrigger) {
     lastAddedLiveFunc();
  }
});
```

**Question: The following code is for creating the endless scroll which fits in the entire webpage, but how can I write the same for a *'div'* inside a web page?**

*(Hint: An exact similar thing is the Ticker on Facebook, on the right side which shows the recent activities of your friends in real time.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principle is the exact same. The div will be your browser viewport, and the div content is your document. You just need to exchange

- `$(window).scroll()` --> `$("#someDiv").scroll()`
- `$(window).scrollTop()` --> `$("#someDiv").scrollTop()`
- `$(document).height()` --> `$("#someDiv")[0].scrollHeight`
- `$(window).height()` --> `$("#someDiv").height()`

and it should work.

**Note that:**

- `scrollHeight` is a property, not a function.
- `scrollHeight` isn't jQuery, so you need to obtain it from the actual javascript element of the selector, hence the `[0]` addition. Another way is to use $("#someDiv").prop("scrollHeight").

Comment: Do you know the equivalent of scrollHeight in jQuery?! I know I can use which was released in jQuery 1.7: $("#dvContent").prop("scrollHeight"); But do you know any pure jQuery equivalent?

Comment: Don't think it exists. $("#dvContent").prop("scrollHeight") or $("#dvContent")[0].scrollHeight seem to be your only options.

Comment: I've tried using it but it doesn't work. Would you please take a look at it and let me know where I've gone wrong and save my life :( ?! 
http://jsfiddle.net/cyrus2013/FQSx4/2/

Comment: You've added the scroll event listener to window instead of the actual div.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#yourdiv").scroll(function(){

//your logic
}
```

You can use your div instead of window

For example

```
$('#yourdiv').scrollTop()  //  etc
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
// get box div position
var box = document.getElementById('box').offsetTop;

window.onscroll = function(){

    // get current scroll position
    var scroll_top = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

    document.getElementById('scbox').innerText = scroll_top + ' ' + box;

    // if current scroll position >= box div position then box position fixed
    if(scroll_top >= box)
        document.getElementById('box').style.position = 'fixed';
    else
        document.getElementById('box').style.position = 'relative';    
}
```

Comment: var scroll_top = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

Comment: Your answer looks interesting! Would you please exemplify in JSFiddle?!